# Can we change highcharts legend to work as radio button instead of checkbox style?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Right now if i use any highcharts, i can see a legend and the legend is clickable, which will toggle the behaviour of the graph.  The legend currently functions as if like a checkbox -- where you can click/toggle multiple items in a legend. I wanted something like at any point of time not more than one option should be selected.

Please let me know if this is possible or not. If so please give me some idea.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is the status of this question?  Did the below answer work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like the [**following**](http://jsfiddle.net/t2MxW/20388/) which will only show the selected series.  Click through the series in the legend to see what it does.

Comment: I updated my answer so that only one series is displayed when the highcharts is first generated.  Click on the above link to the chart to see change. I did this by adding `visible: false,` to all the series except for one.